# Change css of entire list on click in react

Tags: css, reactjs

Made a simple todo app using react. Checkbox on click changes css of respective todo to strikeoff and a button shows on Hover which then deletes the corresponding todo. 
Here i want to implement two things:
1. Change css of entire list of todos on mouse click event on 'x' using react.
2. Change css of individual todos when i click the respective list item.
My app code goes like this.

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      todo:[]
    };
  };

  entertodo(keypress){
    var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
    if( keypress.charCode == 13 )
    {
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, Decor:'newtodo animated fadeInLeft', checked:false})
      });
      this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
    };
  };
  todo(text,i){
    return (
      <li className={text.Decor}>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}className="option-input checkbox" checked={text.checked} />
        <div key={text.id}  className="item">
          {text.Value}
          <button type="button" className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this)}>X</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  };

  remove(i){
    this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
    this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
  };
  todoCompleted(i){
    var todo={...this.state.todo}
    if(todo[i].checked){
      this.state.todo[i].checked = false;
      this.state.todo[i].Decor='newtodo'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
    else {
      this.state.todo[i].checked = true;
      this.state.todo[i].Decor= 'line'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
  };
  **allDone(){
    this.state.todo.style= 'line'
  };**

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
          <div className="lines"></div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
              **<span onClick={this.allDone}id="all">x</span>**
            </div>
          <div className="mainapp">
            <ul>
            {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default App;
```

I created a function named allDone() and assigned it using onClick event to span element'X'. I am not able to change css of all elements in list to strikeoff.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the forEach() statement to add a new class or change the class in the alldone function as. Also you need to  bind this function.

```
allDone= ()=>{
    var todo = this.state.todo;

    todo.forEach(function(item) {
      item.Decor = "newtodo animated fadeInLeft strike"
    })
    this.setState({todo: todo});
  };
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      todo:[]
    };
  };

  entertodo(keypress){
    var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
    if( keypress.charCode == 13 )
    {
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, Decor:'newtodo animated fadeInLeft', checked:false})
      });
      this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
    };
  };
  todo(text,i){
    return (
      <li className={text.Decor}>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}className="option-input checkbox" checked={text.checked} />
        <div key={text.id}  className="item">
          {text.Value}
          <button type="button" className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this)}>X</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  };

  remove(i){
    this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
    this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
  };
  todoCompleted(i){
    var todo={...this.state.todo}
    if(todo[i].checked){
      this.state.todo[i].checked = false;
      this.state.todo[i].Decor='newtodo'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
    else {
      this.state.todo[i].checked = true;
      this.state.todo[i].Decor= 'strike'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
  }; 
  allDone= ()=>{
    var todo = this.state.todo;
    
    todo.forEach(function(item) {
      item.Decor = "newtodo animated fadeInLeft strike"
    })
    this.setState({todo: todo});
  };
 
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
          <div className="lines"></div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
              <span onClick={this.allDone}id="all">x</span>
            </div>
          <div className="mainapp">
            <ul>
            {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }  
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks shubham for help. I also need to change css when i click list item individually.

Comment: i created same function as 'todoCompleted' and assigned to 'li' but nothing is changing when m clicking in li item

Comment: I will see it . I am on mobile now. Will update the answer soon to incorporate that issue as well

Comment: @GauravSoni I think as you have implemented stike functionality on click of chekbox similary you can call an onClick function on the `<li>` element and then operate similarly

Comment: I'm creating a new question for the same problem and adding snippet for the same

Comment: I came up with one more issue, added a new question for it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

**Javascript**

```
allDone() {
    let new_todo = this.state.todo.map((t) => { return { Decor: 'line' } })
    this.setState({ todo: new_todo }); 
}
```

Comment: App is changing a controlled input of type checkbox to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: there is no error in app. Error popping up only if m altering anything to apply new changes